# Report rendering using ReportViewer web control with parameter:

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am using code below to render report.

ASPX:

```
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="654px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" >
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

CodeBehind:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;

        //Set the report server url and report path
        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer");
        serverReport.ReportPath = "/TestReport/TestReport";

        //Create the RequestDateTime report parameter
        ReportParameter requestDateTime = new ReportParameter();
        requestDateTime.Name = "RequestDate";
        requestDateTime.Values.Add("7/30/2014");

        //Set the report parameter for the report
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(
            new ReportParameter[] { requestDateTime });
    }
```

When executed, it just keep saying Loading... 
It acts as if View Report button besides the parameter is been clicked frequently.
The same report loads within a second in the report manager. If I remove the parameter declaration from C# code, and manually provide the parameter value during runtime is working fine.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to print report on `Page_Load` only `If Not Me.Page.IsPostBack`.